# gnuplot--iteration to obtain variables in datafile

Tags: loops, gnuplot

Let's say that I've got data called 'myData.dat' in the form

```
x  y
0  0
1  1
2  2
4  3
8  4
16 5
```

I need to find the following things from this data:

- slope for points

  - 0 to 5
  - 1 to 5
  - 2 to 5
  - 3 to 5
  - 4 to 5
- y-intercept for the same pairs
- equation for the line connecting the same pairs

Then I need to plot the the data and overlay the lines; below is a picture of what I'm asking for.

[image]

I know how to obtain the the slope and y-intercept for a single pair of points, and plot the data and the equation of the line.  For example for points 1 and 5:

```
set table
plot "myData.dat" using 0:($0==0 ? y1=$2 : $2)
plot "myData.dat" using 0:($0==4 ? y5=$2 : $2)
unset table

m1 = (y5 - y1)/(5-1)
b1 = y1 - m1*1
y1(x) = m1*x + b1
```

I'm new to iteration (and gnuplot) and I think there's something wrong with my syntax.  I've tried a number of things and they haven't worked.  My best guess is that it would be in the form

```
plot for [i=1:4] using 0:($0==1 ? y.i=$1 : $1)

do for [i=1:5]{
m.i = (y5 - y.i)/(5-i)
b.i = y.i - m.i*1
y.i(x) = m.i*x + b.i    
}

set multiplot
plot "myData.dat" w lp
plot for [i=1:4] y.1(x)
unset multiplot
```

So what is going wrong?  Is gnuplot able to concatencate the loop counter to variables?

Comment: Gnuplot's scripting abilities are rather limited; it's a plotting program. To do your stuff you would probably be better off using an different scripting language which generates the function strings for the equations which you can then `load`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Although there are other ways to do what you want, for instace using `word(var,i)`, the most straightforward fix to what you already have would be to use `eval` to evaluate a string to which you can concatenate variables:

```
do for [i=1:5]{
eval "m".i." = (y5 - y".i.")/(5-".i.")"
eval "b".i." = y".i." - m".i."*1"
eval "y".i."(x) = m".i."*x + b".i    
}
```

Comment: This works great for obtaining the equation for each pair of points.  As for using the 'plot' function to iterate, I haven't quite figured that one out yet... but like Christoph commented above, gnuplot is quite limited in that regard, so I think I'll attack it from a different angle.

Comment: @chocolate.broccoli I answered to something similar today and remebered your case. Here is how you use`word()` to create arrays and access values within a loop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26819987/1792075